# Translate appllication to Italian

Tags: android, localization

I already translated my app to several different languages like English, French, Deutsch etc. To translate it I used locale qualifiers for `strings.xml` file like `en`, `fr`, `de` etc.

Now I want to add Italian language. I created new `strings.xml` file, putted it in `values-it` directory and launched app. But when I try to change language in application, or change language of device, I can't see Italian translation. All other languages are still work correct, but not Italian. Instead of Italian I see default language (without qualifier). Anybody faced that issue?

There is code to change language

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...

    val countryCode = LocalePref(this).languageCode
    if (countryCode != null) {
      val locale = Locale(countryCode)
      Locale.setDefault(locale)
      val config = resources.configuration
      config.setLocale(locale)
      resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I very sorry before all Italians, if my question offended you. There was very silly mistake from me.

I completely forgot about my app.gradle file:

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ilyin.alchemy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 79
        versionName "1.1.22"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs "en", "de", "es", "fr", "hi", "ja", "ko", "pt", "ru", "zh", "it"

    }
```

I forget to add "it" resConfig to other resConfigs. Once I added it, Italian get work.